# Are there any fixed relationships between mini batch gradient decent and gradient decent

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

For **convex optimization**, like as logistic regression.
For example I have 100 training samples. In `mini batch gradient decent` I set batch size equal to 10.
So after 10 times of `mini batch gradient decent` updating. **Can I get the same result with one times `gradient decent` updating?**

For **non-convex** optimization, like as Neural Network.
I know `mini batch gradient decent` can avoid some local optima sometimes. **But are there any fixed relationships between them.**

Answer (score 6):

When we say batch gradient descent, it is updating the parameters using all the data. Below is an illustration of batch gradient descent. Note each iteration of the batch gradient descent involves a computation of the average of the gradients of the loss function over the entire training data set. In the figure, `-gamma` is the negative of the learning rate.

[image]

When the batch size is 1, it is called stochastic gradient descent (GD).

When you set the batch size to 10 (I assume the total training data size >>10), this method is called mini batches stochastic GD, which is a compromise between true stochastic GD and batch GD (which uses all the training data at one update).  Mini batches performs better than true stochastic gradient descent because when the gradient computed at each step uses more training examples, we usually see smoother convergence. Below is an illustration of SGD. In this online learning setting, each iteration of the update consists of choosing a random training instance (`z_t`) from the outside world and update the parameter `w_t`.

[image]

The two figures I included here are from this [paper](http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/online-1998.pdf).

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent):

> The convergence of stochastic gradient descent has been analyzed using
>   the theories of convex minimization and of stochastic approximation.
>   Briefly, when the learning rates \alpha decrease with an appropriate
>   rate, and subject to relatively mild assumptions, stochastic gradient
>   descent converges almost surely to a global minimum when the objective
>   function is convex or pseudoconvex, and otherwise converges almost
>   surely to a local minimum. This is in fact a consequence of the 
>   Robbins-Siegmund theorem.

Regarding your question:

```
[convex case] Can I get the same result with one times gradient decent updating?
```

If the meaning of "same result" is "converging" to the global minimum, then YES. This is approved by L´eon Bottou in his [paper](http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/online-1998.pdf). That is either SGD or mini batch SGD converges to a global minimum almost surely. Note when we say almost surely:

> It is obvious however that any online learning algorithm can be
>   mislead by a consistent choice of very improbable examples. There is
>   therefore no hope to prove that this algorithm always converges. The
>   best possible result then is the almost sure convergence, that is to
>   say that the algorithm converges towards the solution with probability 1.

For non-convex case, it is also proved in the same paper (section 5), that stochastic or mini batches converges to the local minimum almost surely.